# GraphQL nested mutations

Tags: graphql

I cannot find some example of a schema where the mutations are nested in it's own resolver, to group some actions in a sub-mutations object.

Something like this:

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: RootMutation
}

type RootMutation {
  user: UserMutation
  post: PostMutation
}

type UserMutation {
  create(user: UserInput!): User
  delete(id: ID!): Bool
}

type PostMutation {
  create(user: PostInput!): Post
  delete(id: ID!): Bool
}
```

And the query would be like this:

```
mutation CreateUser($u: UserInput!) {
  user {
    create($u) {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I think that, this approach is completely ok with the specification. So why does everybody design the mutations as a first class function? Like so:

```
type RootMutation {
  createUser(user: UserInput!): User
  deleteUser(id: ID!): Bool

  createPost(user: UserInput!): User
  deletePost(id: ID!): Bool
}
```

When you got a lot of actions to make on your huge system, then the `RootMutation` will have just an endless list of similar functions (like `create`, `delete` and so on).

And isn't this a thing in REST? Where every function is it's own endpoint? But there it's better because you have the HTTP methods. So you would have an `/user` endpoint with a `POST` and a `DELETE` method and so on.